# How do I deny access to a symmetric key alias in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I have a table with some encrypted data:

```
select * from Test1;
```

that yields some rows with garbage data that I created... two rows, both with a name and ciphertext, created by the following command, issued twice with slight variation:

```
insert into Test1 values
('travis', ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('aes128'), convert(varchar, 1234567)));
```

The key was created on the EKM device and aliased in SQL by the following:

```
create symmetric key aes128 from provider EKMProvider with provider_key_name = 'aes128', creation_disposition = open_existing;
```

I have two users: a user (`administrator`) that I want to have unfettered access with full permissions over SQL Server granted, and a second user (`restrictedsql`) that I want to deny access to this encryption key.

Now, if I attempt to use this key as `restrictedsql`, I can `DECRYPT` but I cannot `ENCRYPT`:

```
select ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('aes128'), 'Hello World');
```

yields `NULL`.

However,

```
 select name, CONVERT(varchar, DECRYPTBYKEY(number)) from Test1;
```

yields all of the plaintext data. I believe that the reason that the encrypt function does not work while decrypt does has to do with ddladmin privileges being granted, which is strange but somewhat beside to point: My desired outcome is that this user should have NO access to this key, and any attempt to decrypt or encrypt should fail. The user should retain access to the column and to the ciphertext, just not be able to view the plaintext or to insert properly encrypted data.

I issued the following commands:

```
DENY View Definition ON SYMMETRIC KEY::aes128 TO restrictedsql;
DENY Control ON SYMMETRIC KEY::aes128 TO restrictedsql;
```

They succeed, but do not yield any different results.

Note that the key is EKM-provided, so it is NOT possible to protect the key by wrapping it in a UAC'ed certificate/key. I need to directly UAC the symmetric key alias.

---

Update: I have two scripts that demonstrate the difference in behavior for the permissions statements between native SQL Server AES keys and EKM-provided SQL Server AES keys. Note that this presumes the EKM provider is already created and the key is created on the EKM provider.

First script gets executed by an administrative, full-access user:

```
create table Test2 (
name varchar(25),
ekm128_enc varbinary(256),
local128_enc varbinary(256),
);

CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'sql$server123';

CREATE CERTIFICATE localcert
WITH SUBJECT = 'TestSqlServer';

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY local128 
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_128
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE localcert;

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY ekm128 
FROM PROVIDER EKMProvider 
WITH provider_key_name = 'ekm128', 
creation_disposition = open_existing;

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY local128 DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE localcert;

insert into Test2 values ('travisthomas', ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('ekm128'), 'travisthomas_ekm'), ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('local128'), 'travisthomas_local'));


select name, ekm128_enc, convert(varchar, DECRYPTBYKEY(ekm128_enc)) as ekm128_dec, local128_enc, CONVERT(varchar, DECRYPTBYKEY(local128_enc)) as local128_dec from Test2;
/* execute through this point... the select statement should work flawlessly... the ciphertext and the plaintext should all be visible and not-null */

/* execute after this point next to set the permissions on both ekm128 and local128 */
DENY View Definition ON SYMMETRIC KEY::ekm128 TO restrictedsql;
DENY Control ON SYMMETRIC KEY::ekm128 TO restrictedsql;
DENY View Definition ON SYMMETRIC KEY::local128 TO restrictedsql;
DENY Control ON SYMMETRIC KEY::local128 TO restrictedsql;

select name, ekm128_enc, convert(varchar, DECRYPTBYKEY(ekm128_enc)) as ekm128_dec, local128_enc, CONVERT(varchar, DECRYPTBYKEY(local128_enc)) as local128_dec from Test2;
/* This select statement should provide identical output as the select statement above the "DENY"s */
```

The second script should be executed by the restricted user, restrictedsql in this case.

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY local128 DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE localcert;
/* this statement fails due to lack of permissions */

select name, ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('ekm128'), 'test') as ekm128_encrypt, CONVERT(varchar, decryptbykey(ekm128_enc)) as ekm128_dec, ENCRYPTBYKEY(key_guid('local128'), 'test') as local128_encrypt, CONVERT(varchar, decryptbykey(local128_enc)) as local128_dec from Test2;
/* null for all except EKM decryption! permissions don't apply! */
```

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but in your statement `select name, CONVERT(varchar, DECRYPTBYKEY(number)) from Test1;`, I assume that you're storing the id of the symmetric key that en/decrypts the data alongside the data. Have you checked that the ID is pointing to the key that you think it's pointing to?

Comment: @BenThul Yes, your assumption is correct... the correct key is being retrieved by the EKM provider. The key identifier is stored with the ciphertext.

Comment: The EKM provider is functioning just fine. I need to utilize SQL Server UAC to lock down the symmetric key, though.

Comment: What you are seeing is indeed strange. In my testing, if the user was denied view definition to the symmetric key, the ability to open the key (and thus decrypt the data) was thwarted. Granted (ha!), I don't have an EKM handy and so did my testing with a bog standard symmetric key. It shouldn't matter, but it might.

Comment: The behavior between EKM-managed keys and locally, SQL Server-managed keys does in fact differ. I've raised this issue with Microsoft, and hopefully they will offer a patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I received from Microsoft: this isn't possible in this architecture. The key identifier is bound up in the ciphertext and interpreted by the EKM provider, not SQL Server. SQL Server doesn't even know which key is being used. It would be on the EKM provider to provide UAC.